# Mathjax after Ajax call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

So my problem is as follow:
So firstly, I made a ajax call to another page and replaces some of the elements in my current DOM with the new information, which utilize Mathjax to render their math formulas. However, after my ajax call, Mathjax doesn't seem to be loaded again thus not rendering the math formulas for my new math formulas. Does anyone have encountered this before? What is the solution?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

[This Mathjax documentation page](http://www.mathjax.org/docs/1.1/typeset.html) should help you a lot.

For example, it has `MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);` method call to update every new node on the page.

Comment: I'm having same problem, I added this code  "MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);" but it does not do anything. I also run in firebug console but no effect.

Comment: Because its async. You literally adding `Typeset()` call to the queue. Try to call `MathJax.Hub.Typeset()` in console but its not recommended to use it like this in production

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `Daniel O'Hara` answer you also might try to call `MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Reprocess",MathJax.Hub])`. Or call `MathJax.Hub.Typeset()` directly but its not recommended to do so in production